# Controlling number of producer per jms connection in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, ems

Currently, I'm engaged in testing a TIBCO EMS application, aiming to simulate a high transaction rate using Gatling version 3.9.3. During preliminary exploratory tests, I observed that Gatling creates a single JMS connection and utilizes multiple producers—specifically, 8 producers in this instance—to generate messages.

For my upcoming test, I aim to employ a single connection with only 5 producers. I'm seeking guidance on whether Gatling provides a method to control the number of producers in such scenarios.

The current setUp looks like this

setUp(
Persistentmessage4.inject(constantUsersPerSec(persistent_TPS) during (TestDuration seconds)).protocols(jmsProtocol_per4)
)

Answer (score 0):

Gatling creates 1 JMS Session per even loop, hence twice your number of cores. It's not possible to tune it.